# how to access resource dictionary in a WPF class Library?

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary, class-library

Here is the scenario.
I have a WPF project A which is the startup project. And a class library B containing Views and Images. 
Both A and B have images. I have set them as resource.
In a i have declared my resources of A in App.xaml using merged resource dictionary.

Now i want to declare a resource dictionary in B and use the resources in views defined in B.
Please Help.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Pack URI Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) to create references to XAML resources located in separate assemblies.